# Получение исходного кода страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Есть некий сайт. Мне необходимо средствами Python получить ее исходный код. Проблема в том, что он генерируется средствами Javascript, и `requests.get()` возвращает отнюдь не то, что мне нужно (страницу со скриптом, который загружает с некого сервера код страницы).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import re

url = "https://beru.ru/deals"
manager = urllib3.PoolManager()
page = manager.urlopen('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(page.data), "html.parser")

with open('page.txt', 'w') as FILE:
    FILE.write(str(page.data))

a = soup.find_all( class_="_3ioN70chUh Usp3kX1MNT _3Uc73lzxcf")
```

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Selenium.​​‌‌‌​‍‌‌​​‌​‌​‍‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​‌‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​​‌​​‍​‌‌‌‌​​​​​‌‍​‌‌‌‌​​‌‌​

Comment: Вам нужно то, что поддерживает обработку js. Например: [selenium](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a7b4a43b9f57a3ffd7e5a755ca5b4c5fb480b07a/selenium__examples/hello_world.py), еще можно попробовать https://github.com/psf/requests-html (там про поддержку js написано) еще в pyqt5 есть [QWebEngineView](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5357b43e6ba234a85d439dd1e5af90957820a36b/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QWebEngine__append_custom_javascript__jQuery__with_select_color/main.py#L30)